# Custom Comparator in Java works, but with a flaw

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I need to write an algorithm that accepts 10 items from the user, be it strings or numbers which is then put into an array and my program is supposed to sort the array. I am not allowed to use Java's method for comparing or sorting. It should be my own code.

The program I wrote works well enough it sorts strings fine and it will sort numbers that are single digits fine too.

However if a double digit number is entered, it is treated as a single digit because my program looks at the first character for comparison. For example 1 and 10 will be sorted next to each other. I know what the problem is, but I don't know how else to write my own comparator class that accepts a general object.

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object items[] = new Object[10];
        Object item;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        SelectionSorter sorter = new SelectionSorter();

        System.out.println("Please enter 10 items to be sorted: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            item = scanner.nextLine();

            items[i] = item;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here are the items in ascending order: ");
        items = sorter.sortInAscendingOrder(items);
        printArray(items);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here are the items in descending order: ");
        items= sorter.sortInDescendingOrder(items );
        printArray(items);
    }

    public static void printArray(Object[] items)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(items[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.print(items[items.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

```
public class SelectionSorter
{
    Object temp;
    Compare compare;

    public SelectionSorter()
    {

        temp = "";
        compare = new Compare();
    }

    public Object[] sortInAscendingOrder(Object[] n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < n.length; j++)
            {
                if (compare.compareItems(n[i],n[j]))
                {
                    temp = n[i];
                    n[i] = n[j];
                    n[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        return n;
    }

    public Object[] sortInDescendingOrder(Object[] n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n.length; j++)
            {
                if (!compare.compareItems(n[i],n[j]))
                {
                    temp = n[i];
                    n[i] = n[j];
                    n[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

```
public class Compare
{
    int a;
    int b;

    public Compare()
    {
        a = b = 0;
    }

    public boolean compareItems(Object item1, Object item2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < item1.toString().length() && i < item2.toString().length(); i++)
        {
            a = item1.toString().toLowerCase().charAt(i);
            b = item2.toString().toLowerCase().charAt(i);

            if (a > b)
            {
                return true;
            } else if (a < b)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your class implement the Comparable<T> interface?  You wrote too much code.

Comment: Why does it only look at the first character? Do you always want to sort numerically, e.g., if you get a string do you want to convert it to a number?

Comment: You actually **can't** compare strings and numbers the same way.  Given the level of coursework, what you you have might be fine.  Have you asked your instructor?

Comment: You need a clear definition of what your comparison function will return, if you want to compare "strings or numbers".  Do you want to compare numbers by comparing their values, but compare strings by comparing them alphabetically?  What happens if you compare a string to a number?  You have to handle this very carefully to make sure you obey the rules for comparison (i.e. for a total ordering), or else you can get exceptions when you sort.

Comment: @DaveNewton  He actually does use a loop to compare strings.  What I think he is saying is that if a numeric string is only one digit long, it sorts based on the first character -- not what you'd normally expect for a number.  But correct for a string.

Comment: Also, your `compareItems` is wrong.  What if `toString()` returns `"ab"` on one object, and `"abc"` on the other?  Your code will always return `true`, which means that it says `"ab"` < `"abc"` and `"abc"` < `"ab"`, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: after the loop ends (where you just return true without any test) you could test the lengths of the strings.  Shorter strings sort before longer strings.

Comment: Yeah i know its a bit weird. I first wrote a program that sorted only strings which worked fine, then he asked me to change it to use Object[] instead of String[] so that the program is not limited to strings

Comment: But you end up calling `toString()` on the Object, so that's a weird request.  It doesn't actually work on non-strings, as you see.  I think you'd have to duplicate Java's `Comparable` interface and all of it's machinery to get this to truly work on Object, and that sounds beyond the scope of your current level of coursework.

Comment: FYI, there's a fatal flaw in your design, although I assume you are following instructions.  When you compare, there are three possible results, not two, so returning just true/false doesn't work.  Java's `Comparable` gets around this by returning an integer value: -1 means less than, +1 means greater than, and 0 means equal.

Comment: @markspace doesnt the loop iterate until it finds one bigger than the other? kind of avoiding the equal condition

Comment: If the loop get all the way to the end and doesn't find one bigger or smaller, then the strings are equal.  In that case you just return true.  It also returns true if one string is shorter than another, and the first digits all match.  "1" and "12" for example, it will test the first character, then fall out of the loop because the length of the first string, 1, is less than the condition test for your for loop to continue.

Comment: Just FYI, _"bare with me"_ means "let's remove our clothes together".  Not what you intended, I'm sure.  It's "bear with me".

Comment: @markspace just to be precise: the `compare()` method in `Comparable` or `Comparator` returns a value < 0 for less than, > 0 for greater than.  It is wrong to assume it to be -1 and +1

Answer (score -1):

Your assignment is somewhat underspecified:

1. May the user mix numbers and strings?
2. When you say numbers, does that include

   - negative numbers?
   - numbers of arbitrary length?
   - grouping separators (as in 9,100)?
   - decimal separators (as in 9.32)?
   - scientific notation (as in 9.34e+7)
   - SI prefixes (as in 9K)
   - number systems other than decimal (positional or otherwise)?
   - special symbols like ∞ ?

Since this is a school assignment, I am going to assume non-negative integers of arbitrary length :-)

To come up with an algorithm, think about how you compare numbers by hand. Most likely, after checking that neither has a decimal point, you'd compare their length (longer numbers being bigger), and if both numbers are equally long, we can compare them digit by digit, just like strings.

In code, this would look something like this:

```
boolean less(String a, String b) {
    if (isNumber(a)) {
        if (isNumber(b)) {
            return numericLess(a,b);
        } else {
            return true; // number before strings
        }
    } else {
        if (isNumber(b)) {
            return false; 
        } else {
            return alphabeticLess(a,b);
        }
    }
}

boolean numericLess(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length < b.length) {
        return true;
    } else if (a.length > b.length) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return alphabeticLess(a,b);
    }
}
```